# Oracle Default Column Value Calculated Date

Tags: oracle, default-value

I am trying to create a table that has a default value for a date that is sysdate - 2 in oracle

Oracle seems to be fine with sysdate as the default but not sysdate - 2.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the DEFAULT value in brackets:

Create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE order_status (
  order_id NUMBER,
  last_modified DATE DEFAULT (SYSDATE - 2)
);
```

Insert a record to test the default:

```
INSERT INTO order_status
(order_id)
VALUES
(1);
```

Select the data from the table to confirm the default worked (Current date 14/11/2011):

```
SELECT *
  FROM order_status;

ORDER_ID  LAST_MODIFIED
       1  12/11/2011
```

DB Version 10g.

Hope it helps...